# Angular 7 - Material - Table column filters and column sorting - Edge

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-material

I am trying to combine specific columns filtering and column sorting with material table.
On chrome it works just fine but i cannot manage to make it work with Edge, which is my targeted browser...

On edge, I cannot access the column filter text field, it just sorts the column.

Here is a stackblitz matching my issue : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-9enmx4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your Stackblitz example running in Edge? I try to run it in Edge but it shows 'Out of stack space' error.

Comment: It does with IE11 running as Edge debugger (I have no choice as we run on Windows 7 computers).

Comment: Not sure, how you are accessing it. Stackblitz example shows a blank page while opening with IE 11 browser.

Comment: Try with the app link instead of the one with the code included, it works on my side. https://angular-hbakxo-9enmx4.stackblitz.io

Comment: I tried to check it with IE and I can see that issue there. I check the code and I try to compare it with another example. I noticed that you did not use type="text" in this line. <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="nameFilter" placeholder="Name Filter" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"> You can try to add it and test with it.

Comment: Sadly it does not change anything.

Comment: Ok so I managed to go around the issue by moving the mat-sort-header into a dedicated span. Not an ideal solution but at least it does the trick for now...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the workaround for the issue. I suggest you post your workaround as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround to my issue.
Instead of using the tag mat-sort-header in the th, I used a dedicated span in the th.

```
<span mat-sort-header></span>
```

It just needs a bit of css to render in the correct position but it does the trick.
Here is the edited stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbakxo-9enmx4

Comment: You can mark your own answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I can't for like 4 hours or so. I will do it in the afternoon.